# UpdateOrCreate on one to many relationship

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

### UPDATED

i am trying to apply `update_or_create` method on parent table. Then on child table. But when the `update_or_create` method run on the child there is this error returns...

> save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object
>   'atom_presance'.

it's look like child doesn't know parent's `update_or_create` and can't get the foreign_key.

```
for i, fee in enumerate(fees):
   for j, item in enumerate(fee):
      projects = AtomPresance() #parent
      advertisements = Advertisements() #child

      project_name = {'project_name': item["title"]}

      kind = item["kind"]
      removed_price = {'removed_price': item[kind], "atom_presance":projects} #sending FOREIGN_KEY also

      obj, created = AtomPresance.objects.update_or_create(project_name=item["title"], defaults=project_name)
      obj, created = Advertisements.objects.update_or_create(saved_date=date, defaults=removed_price)
```

what is the best way to use `update_or_create` on parent and child in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got error when you are `update_or_create` second method in defaults values assign `removed_price` as dictionary put after the first creating
`AtomPresance` objects and assign key value in `atom_presance=obj` of `removed_price` dictionary

> you have must pass the reference of parentmodel in childmodel creation replace below code with your code

```
for i, fee in enumerate(fees):
   for j, item in enumerate(fee):
      project_name = {'project_name': item["title"]}

      kind = item["kind"]

      obj, created = AtomPresance.objects.update_or_create(project_name=item["title"], defaults=project_name)

      removed_price = {'removed_price': item[kind], "atom_presance":obj} #here change you need to assign the created obj that we create in above line 

      obj, created = Advertisements.objects.update_or_create(saved_date=date, defaults=removed_price)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it's not working because in child's table `parent_id` is can't be null.

Comment: I update my query can you try this ,can you specify model.py so we understand clear also provide you

Comment: error says: `TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <AtomPresance: >.` I updated the question with the　`model`

Comment: If not work please update your questions and specify your model class with field

Comment: i update my answer as per your model so check it it work's or not

Comment: thank you. I updated and made a big change on the question. could you please take a look at?

Comment: you can't change whole question here the answer is wrong base on it you must to ask new question it proved wrong

Comment: the things is the question is still has the same logic, creating and updating the child table based on the foreign_key of the parent. I just applied a much lesser code with `update_or_create` method, but I am really appreciate of your help.

Comment: can you provide the model first which fields you have how can we understand and which value come in fees can you give so better to understand what the field kind or etc

Comment: i update my answer pls check it, if it work or not let me know

Comment: thank you, it like you said, I passed the obj and solved it.